# Kafka-how to send messages to specific partition based on a table's field value via Debezium configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

is it possible to send messages to specific partition based on a table field value? For example,i have a column called customer, which has 4 values ,say customer1,customer2,customer3,customer4. I want to send to their corresponding partition.

is it posiible to achive this in debezium configuration?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Debezium will write Kafka records into partitions based on the record key, e.g. the database rows id. There's no guarantee "customer1" goes to "partition 1", or that 2 customers will end up in the same partition (e.g. you may have more customers than partitions)

To explicitly map the data to numbered partitions, you'll need to implement your own `Partitioner` Java interface and add it to the Connect worker classpath and set `producer.override.partitioner.class` in the Debezium config.

Or you can just let the producer partition based on the key of the records, as is expected.